# MEF ImportCardinalityMismatchException

Tags: c#, mef

**System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException
'No exports were found that match the constraint: ContractName  IntroToMEF.DigitalMonitor
                                                  RequiredTypeIdentity  IntroToMEF.IMonitor'
'**

My types are correct. I am able to Get exported value if I have only one instance inheriting from IMonitor. Whenever I need to use contract name I get an error. I am out of ideas.

**Clearing Visual Studio Cache does not work.**

```cs
[Export(typeof(IMonitor))]
public class DigitalMonitor : IMonitor
{
    public void start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digital Monitor: Started monitoring");
    }
}

internal class HostMefInApp
{
    [Import]
    public ILogger logger { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public IMonitor monitor { get; set; }

    private void ComposeMultiple()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG:" + GetType().Assembly);
        var assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(GetType().Assembly);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(assemblyCatalog);

        //  var contractName = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(typeof(FileLogger));

        try
        {
            var instancesOfFileLogger = container.GetExports<ILogger>(); //"IntroToMEF.FileLogger"
        }
        catch (ImportCardinalityMismatchException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
        batch.AddPart(AttributedModelServices.CreatePart(new FileLogger()));
        batch.AddPart(AttributedModelServices.CreatePart(new DigitalMonitor()));
        batch.AddPart(AttributedModelServices.CreatePart(new AnalogMonitor()));


        container.Compose(batch);

        var digitalMonitorContractName = AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(typeof(DigitalMonitor));
        var currentLogger = container.GetExportedValue<ILogger>();
        var digitalMonitor = container.GetExportedValue<IMonitor>(digitalMonitorContractName);


        logger = currentLogger;
        monitor = digitalMonitor;         
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should:

```
[Export(typeof(IMonitor))]
[Export(typeof(DigitalMonitor))]
public class DigitalMonitor : IMonitor
{
    public void start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Digital Monitor: Started monitoring");
    }
}
```

meaning, export DigitalMonitor as IMonitor and DigitalMonitor. This will give you possibility to import it using both ways. Then of course your code will work with:

```
var digitalMonitor = container.GetExportedValue<DigitalMonitor>();
```